# Set-Cookie session not being set after sign_in with cross-domain

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, api, devise, cors

I have a rails app that has 2 subdomains:

- **API** (CORS) => `api.myapp.dev`
- **Web App** => `myapp.dev`

I can only access my API via `auth_token` which is returned right after user's authentication using Devise. However, my client (web app) is not setting these cookies. Am I missing something?

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Api::V1::BaseController

  def create
    @user = User.find_for_database_authentication(:email => params[:user][:email])

    if @user and @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
      sign_in @user # Set-Cookie header response with the session
      render "api/v1/users/preview", :handlers => :rabl # return auth_token here
    else
      flash[:error] = I18n.t('devise.failure.invalid')
      render "api/v1/base/error", :handlers => :rabl, :status => :unprocessable_entity 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons you can't set cookies from cross-domain websites. However, `jQuery.ajax` let's you do this by explicitly setting the following options:

```
$.ajax
  type: "POST"
  url: "api.mydomain.com/login"
  xhrFields:
    withCredentials: true
```

Also, make sure to return `headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true"` from your HTTP response.